# Creating a multiselect lookup row in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet of activities that looks something like this

| Activity Name | Category Ids |
| --- | --- |
| Activity 1 | 123456, 98756, 345677 |

I have a second sheet of category ids

| Category Id | Category Name |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | Category1 |
| 98756 | Category 2 |
| 345677 | Category 3 |

Here's a [link to a sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dcP9uvMFay-dkaNr_vZ4frJKmxA7U9-xWHhqEyoglw8/edit?usp=sharing)

What I would like to do is create a column in the activity sheet that displays the names of all of the categories that are in the category Ids field for that activity.

Is this possible in Google Sheets? So far, I haven't even been able to get a simple lookup to work on multiple id's in the id's field (see my spreadsheet). I've also looked at [this article on implementing multiple-select dropdown lists](https://spreadsheetpoint.com/multiple-selection-drop-down-google-sheets/), but haven't implemented it because I am not sure how to deal with the fact that in my case, the dropdown list needs to be pre-populated with the values already in Category IDs.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: It sounds like you are asking several questions: `1` how to find category names by a list of IDs, `2` how to create a drop-down list, `3` how to make a spreadsheet work like a custom database system. I am answering the first question below. You may want to ask the two other questions separately, and consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219). Also see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The category IDs are of varying lengths, which means that simple string matching cannot be used because of the risk of matching a key like 1234 with a key like 123456. To get started, try `filter()` with `regexmatch()`, like this:

```
=textjoin( 
  ", ", 
  true, 
  filter( 
    Categories!B$2:B, 
    regexmatch(B2, "\b" & Categories!A$2:A & "\b") 
  ) 
)
```

Here is the same formula, adjusted to your sample spreadsheet:

```
=textjoin( 
  ", ", 
  true, 
  iferror( 
    filter( 
      Grade!B$2:B, 
      regexmatch( 
        regexextract(D2, "'(.+)'"), 
        "\b" & Grade!C$2:C & "\b" 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

The formula should go to cell `Sheet1!F2`. Copy it down to extend it to further rows.

To learn the exact [regular expression](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Comment: Thaks for this. The id's are actually unique 12 byte object ID's from MongoDB. I was just making up values for the mock example above.